# Map on Website not see, but if I click on F12 for debug then it sudendly happen

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I have notice that when I run my page on browser which contain the MAP, then the square is gray out but the map is loaded as I can place pin.
Then if I press only once the F12 key to be in debug mode, then suddenly the MAP appears and the remains.

My code is below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < PinList.length; i++) {
            var beach = PinList[i];
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: beach["Latitude"], lng: beach["Longitude"] },
                map: map,
                title: beach["Name"],
                index: i,
                id: beach["Id"]
            });
}
```

Using above code, i will get list of lat,long to be displayed on Map. But the map is not showed untill i press F12.

Please help.

Comment: Please take a moment to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map is displayed after applied internal CSS for height on div just above the MAP.

Answer (score 0):

Check for how are you submitting the page. Put up your code for reviewing. You are probably submitting the page before even the map loads on the page. That may be the reason you have to give one more refresh for the values to loaded on to map.